# Automatically change Terminal colors on remote connection?

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to automatically apply a terminal profile when connected to a remote machine via SSH?

I'd like more obvious visual cues that I'm connected to a remote machine than the user/host displayed on each terminal line. I spend most of my day connected to multiple machines and it can get confusing.

Comment: What I do now is have separate gnome-terminal launchers for each machine I connect to.  Each launcher opens with a different profile and window size.  If this could be somehow be made to automagically change when I connect to a server from any terminal it would be awesome.  Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Srigelsford](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=536437) from the Ubuntu forums [recommends](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10240905#post10240905) this:

> I created several profiles in
>   gnome-terminal with the settings I
>   wanted, then created aliases like the
>   below example to ssh to ares. The Ares
>   profile has a red background.
>
> ```
> alias -p ares='gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Ares -x bash -c "ssh ares"; exit'
> ```
>
> The pitfall of this is that it cannot
>   be done in your existing terminal
>   window, it launches another. My alias
>   closes the existing one after
>   launching the new one, but you can
>   stop that by removing the ; exit from
>   the end.
>
> Just create as many profiles as you
>   like, and associate each server to a
>   profile in an alias. To launch just
>   type the name of the alias $ares

Comment: +1 and I might add your Screen Name ***groovehunter*** will meet it's objective (after a decade or 9 years and 9 months) with the arrival of Ubuntu 20.10 aka ***"Groovy Gorilla"***.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for gnome3 terminals.   It uses xdotool to automate interaction with the gnome terminal menu, since the available keyboard shortcuts are currently limited.

I have created two profiles.  The top one in the Terminal->Profiles menu is my default, and indicates a local machine.  The second one is my color scheme for a remote connection to machine66.

I then defined the following aliases in my bashrc:

```
alias first_profile="xdotool key F10 Right Right Right Right Down Right Return"
alias second_profile="xdotool key F10 Right Right Right Right Down Right Down Return"
alias go66="second_profile; ssh remotemachine66; first_profile"
```

The first_profile and second_profile just use xdotools to click f10 (open the menu), and then traverse right to terminal, down 1 to profiles selection,  and then select the first or second profile.

go66 first calls second_profile to set the colors, ssh's into the remote machine.  On exiting ssh first_profile is called, returning the profile to the local profile.

It's clunky, but it works.  I'm happy to hear refinement suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i had that on my todolist for quite some time and just tried and searched againg

this is also a reminder to myself: Have to try with screen / byobu

For now i use gnome-terminal profiles . The config files are xml in HOME/.gconf/apps ... and so i might create / copy them via script lateron for some 20 to 50 hosts, with automatically created colors etc. As i write i see and have to admit it is not very sophisticated idea though.

For now i need a easier to type short cut then ALT+D R 0  to open new tab with profile #0 (german shortcut)

Comment: and add this http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=536437